# htaccess removing directory from url makes page not open

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page called about.php inside a folder called 'pages'.

I successfully removed the .php and the directory from the url, but now the page isn't opening.

All my files are inside **localhost/test/** folder.
so everything used to open normally as **localhost/test/pages/about.php**
now it shows **localhost/test/about** and doesn't open.

```
RewriteBase /test/    
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ $1 [L,NC,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're actually trying to achieve? You're trying to redirect requests to `mysite.com/about` to the internal file `/test/about.php` ?

Comment: yeah. localhost/test/about internal redirect to localhost/test/pages/about.php. I seems to work in the url but the page doesn't load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pages/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^pages/(.+)$ $1 [L,NC,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ pages/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```